# HTML inserted into bootstrap modal not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, innerhtml

I am trying to build a web page that contains populates a bootstrap modal from an Html file stored on the same pc. However, it is currently displaying weirdly as can be seen in this image

[image]

This is my first time posting here and I am self-taught so if this is a stupid mistake - sorry.
I am trying to build a page with a list of stories. I want the stories to open my in a modal. To stop the page itself getting ridiculously long the stories themselves are stored in their own Html files (including formatting) and inserted using javascript - inner HTML.
The webpage includes bootstrap 4 and jquery

the relevant code is

```html
<button onclick="fetchStory('Solitude')"> Read </button>

<div class="modal" id="displayStory" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="fetchStoryLabel" aria-hidden="true">

    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="fetchStoryLabel">New message</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="sample">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <center>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
             function fetchStory(story) {
  var modal = $(displayStory)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text(story)
    var story_path = "samples\\" + story + ".html"
    document.getElementById("sample").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data=' + story_path + '></object>'
    $('#displayStory').modal()

}   

    </script>
```

If I passed the Html directly into the modal it displays as expected but when inserted using javascript it displays as above. inspecting it on a web page I cannot see any reason for the difference

Comment: What if you analyze the content with the devtools of your browser?

Comment: It looks like your width is being reduced. Try this just to see if it changes the display.... document.getElementById('sample').style.width = '100%';

Comment: It looks like the default size of the modal is why your display looks like that. I'm not familiar with the bootstrap stuff. Just trying to help.

Comment: Assuming the fact that you haven't modified the default modal css of bootstrap, maybe just check the css of the html file your importing and if it has a fixed width set, remove that.

Comment: When I inspect elements in chrome I cannot see a difference between opening the html or having it in the web page.

Comment: adding .style.with='100%' didn't change anything. The html file I am importing doesn't have any css in it. They are just the text with html codes (<p>, <h1> <em> etc) to format the text.